# readOnly attribute not being set with JavaScript function in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am trying to create an edit link such that when it is clicked it opens the details for that row in read-only mode.

Here is the link:

```jsp
<c:set var="deletableBook" value="0"/>

<a href="" title="Edit Book Info" onClick='resetDateAndMakeReadOnly(${deletableBook}); return performAction(${item.bookId}, "bookEdit");'>Edit</a>
```

And here's the function that gets called:

> ```
> function resetDateAndMakeReadOnly(allEditable) {      
>  var e22 = document.getElementById('book_Date');
>  var e3 = document.getElementById('book_type');
>  var e4 = document.getElementById('book_Number');
>  if (allEditable){
>      e22.readOnly=false;
>      e3.disabled=false;
>      e4.readOnly=false;
>      alert("read and write");
>  } else {
>      e22.readOnly=true;
>      e3.disabled=true;
>      e4.readOnly=true;
>      alert("readOnly new");
>  }
>  e22.value = "<c:out value='${params.book_Date}'/>";
>  return false;    }
> ```

And currently nothing seems to change when this method is run.  I've confirmed that it makes it to the correct part of the logic, but things are still editable.

Comment: @gdoron Sorry updated description.  Basically setting it to readOnly doesn't seem to make it read only

Comment: By any chance wouldn't that generate duplicated IDs (if you have multiple rows)? Also make sure that your back-end tags are parsed into the HTML and value you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using link with empty `href` to trigger your javascript function which will reload your page. Use `javascript:void(0);` inside `href`.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Edit Book Info" onClick='resetDateAndMakeReadOnly(${deletableBook}); return performAction(${item.bookId}, "bookEdit");'>Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `deletableBook` is not a boolean value, and is not `false` that you expect in the javascript function. To switch the variable in the action

```
session.put("allEditable", !(session.get("allEditable")==null?Boolean.FALSE:(Boolean)session.get("allEditable")));
```

then use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resetDateAndMakeReadOnly(<s:property value="%{#session.allEditable}"/>);
});
```

that will reset fields attributes depending on `allEditable` when the page is reloaded. But this

```
<s:a href="" title="Edit Book Info" onClick="resetDateAndMakeReadOnly(%{#session.allEditable});">Make readonly</s:a>
```

will not reload the page and keep the value that you have in the `allEditable` session attribute. That syntax may be a little bit confuse the IDE but is correctly evaluate the OGNL expression and renders like

```
<a title="Edit Book Info" onClick="resetDateAndMakeReadOnly(false);">Make readonly</a>
```

there's no `href` attribute, that's why the page is not reloaded.

Also elements in the JSP should be findable by their `id` attribute should be set.